# run one javascript function for different element

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how run one javascript function for diffrent element with one ASP.Net button click ?

Comment: yes that is possible if first set up click on the almost closer to the element you want with the dom.

Comment: an example will be so good, thanks

Answer (score 0):

for example if you want to run another button's click event function you can call `document.getElementById('myButton').click();`

but remember, if click function of that button is doing postback, you need to prevent it. because that calling that function will avoid the code from continuing.

Comment: And note that Firefox may not support the click on that element. More code needed for that.